# Encrypt in layers? -or am I a naive newb?

Tags: security, encryption

If, (1) you’re only encrypting files of small to moderate size, and/or (2) you don’t need en/decrypt to be fast, and (3) you have a safe way to distribute/hide the decrypting executable…  Then, couldn’t you EASILY write an en/decrypter that works this way:

A) Encrypt using a respected off-the-shelf algorithm with a BIG random key.
B) Generate random bytes and sprinkle them in random places (<= doubling the size).
C) Mix that up with your own custom (even simple) reversible bit flipping loop.
D) Repeat ABC, 5-10 times, using a different (random) algorithm and random bytes for each step.
E) Collect all the randomly generated stuff into one file -one big key.

Sure, I get it, a naive implementation could balloon a 1K email into 1M, with a 100K key, but it only takes a few seconds to think up a dozen ways to get those sizes under control.

And, sure, I get that passing these big files around with their big keys would be suspicious, but again, it seems pretty easy to hide such files in large media files, such as images/audio/etc.

And, sure, sure, I get that protecting the en/decrypt app IS the weakness, but again, it seems easily to hide that feature in some viewer/converter/compressor of such large media files.

So, is this a thing?  With a name?  Does anyone do this or am I just a naive newb missing something fundamental?

Comment: Ok but... why? What would be the purpose? Would this be some kind of steganography?

Comment: It seemed to me that many of the weaknesses of encryption algorithms are only because they have to be fast.  So I am wondering if this sort of approach is how many en/decrypt where speed/time is not an issue, and where you need to transfer files over public networks without fear of some clever mathematician or hacker eventually cracking the ONE alg that you used....or does my idea just move the one-alg vulnerability to a one-app vulnerability?

Comment: @Til Maybe have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_encryption)

Comment: ...or [hybrid crypto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem) is another common approach somewhat along these lines

Comment: @Til consider asking at [Cryptography SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/)..your question will be very probably closed here as it has nothing to do with programming

Comment: What is a weakness of AES that you think is due to it's speed? NIST would be interested as well as the designers.